# Need to get my location while my app is in the background

Tags: ios, ios6, background, cllocation

I'm writing a basic location based alarm/notification app for my beginning IOS class. I have the locations objects (CLLocation) but I can't figure out how to check for current location in the background. I am not worried about battery usage, just need to periodically get a current location so I can check if its close to the alarm location then notify the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be worried about battery usage but Apple is and thus you'll need to use the provided Apple frameworks.

Look into `EKAlarm` and specifically:

```
@property EKStructuredLocation *structuredLocation
```

You also have in `CLLocationManager`:

```
- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

Here is part of the description for `CLLocationManager`:

> In iOS, the
>   regions you register with the location manager persist between
>   launches  of your application. If a region crossing occurs while your
>   iOS app is not running,  the system automatically wakes it up (or
>   relaunches it) in the background so that  it can process the event.
>   When relaunched, all of the regions you configured  previously are
>   made available in the monitoredRegions property of any location 
>   manager objects you create.

Comment: I'm only trying to get a grade and be able to demo this app in class. I know that this app will not be ready to go on the app store by the time it is due.

Comment: startMonitoringForRegion and didUpdateLocations can I just put these in my AppDelegate under applicationDidEnterBackground?

Comment: I think I answered your question.  Upvote and check; then post another question for how to use `startMonitoringForRegion:`